# F-testing formula in R

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am trying to test my linear model. The output from `lm()` function is as follows:

```
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 1615.2716    83.2051   19.41   <2e-16 ***
rts$angle     11.8387     0.8895   13.31   <2e-16 ***
```

I wanted to test the null hypothesis, which gave me following output:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2503.17      70.04   35.74   <2e-16 ***
```

Now, I am using the F-testing formula:

```
(rss0 <- deviance(nullmod))
# [1] 158056425
(rss <- deviance(rtsld))
# [1] 79219962
(df0 <- df.residual(nullmod))
# [1] 179
(df <- df.residual(rtsld))
# [1] 178
(fstat <- ((rss0-rss)/(df0-df))/(rss/df))
# [1] 177.1383
1-pf(fstat, df0-df, df)
# [1] 0
```

I do not understand why I am getting 0 for the `p-value` of my `f-statistic`. Could someone please help me to understand this output?

Comment: Any chance you could post the data?

Comment: Wrap your last line in `format.pval()`. (You can find this p-value also in the output of `summary(full_model_fit)`).

Comment: @ Roland Thank you! This works and gives me  following output: "< 2.22e-16". If I could ask one more question, what is the reason for getting the 0 value in the first place? Is it a problem with the precision value? I used: `.Machine$double.eps` which gave me `[1] 2.220446e-16`.

Comment: Would also like to hear if anyone knows the reason why the lower.tail=TRUE returned a 1 (which resulted in the 0 value) instead of a more precise estimate. If anyone has a tad more technical know-how, that could definitely sate my curiosity as I've been looking for that answer for the past half hour without any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pf()` function has a default for `lower.tail=TRUE`. This means, that the F-test performed is defaulted to a lower tailed test. In a F-test we always use an upper-tailed test (for a great explanation, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67543/why-do-we-use-a-one-tailed-test-f-test-in-analysis-of-variance-anova)). While it makes intuitive sense to calculate the upper tailed test with `1-pf()`, R needs a bit of prodding to make it work this way. This is because, when you have a large effect, the lower tail can very easily return a value that is so incredibly close to 1, that R doesn't recognize the floating point (or so I've been told, I'm not entirely sure how accurate this is as I haven't looked at the raw code of the `pf()` function).

@Roland already posed the solution of wrapping your `1-pval()` call with the `format.pval()`, as this forces R to recognize the p-value. However, I would argue to use the command:

```
pf(fstat, df0-df, df, lower.tail=FALSE)
```

This returns a more accurate upper.tailed test. When you wrap this in the `format.pval()` command, you get the same result as when you use the `format.pval(1 - pf())` command. This is because format.pval is bounded to round up. However, when using format.pval with increased shown decimals using the `1 - pf(lower.tail=TRUE)` formula is incapable of reconstructing the more accurate estimate.

```
    > pf(fstat, df0-df, df, lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 0.0000000000000000000000000001685664
> format.pval(pf(fstat, df0-df, df, lower.tail=FALSE), eps=0.0000000000000000000000000001)
[1] "0.00000000000000000000000000016857"
> format.pval(1-pf(fstat, df0-df, df, lower.tail=TRUE), eps=0.0000000000000000000000000001)
[1] "< 0.0000000000000000000000000001"
```

Note that even now, the `format.pval` wrap on the upper-tailed test is rounding up. Of course, when your p-value is this small (and in fact, the entire issue arises only when your p-value is very small), there's hardly a difference between the two methods. But why settle for less accurate?

Comment: If anybody can enlighten me on why exactly the lower-tailed `pf()` test returned a 1, I would love to hear it. The explanation of not recognizing the float point isn't entirely satisfactory to me.